Utilize polars library to compute Levenshtein distance
I have sequences in the form of tuples in a column of a pandas DataFrame. A sample of my DataFrame is the following:
id       sequence
33268    [(59, 2), (91, 2), (112, 2), (126, 2), (0, 3),...
44360    [(137, 0), (208, 0), (251, 0), (0, 1), (46, 1)...
51943    [(117, 0), (153, 1), (190, 1), (0, 7), (218, 7...
53888    [(0, 0), (18, 0), (58, 0), (69, 0), (86, 0), (...
38505    [(0, 1), (96, 1), (131, 1), (188, 1), (229, 1)...

I want to compute the minimum Levenshtein distance between each sequence with a list of several other sequences of the same form. Lets say that this list is  l= [...]
I have found the following implementation of Levenshtein distance:
def levenshtein(s, t):
    if s == t: return 0
    elif len(s) == 0: return len(t)
    elif len(t) == 0: return len(s)
    v0 = [None] * (len(t) + 1)
    v1 = [None] * (len(t) + 1)
    for i in range(len(v0)):
        v0[i] = i
    for i in range(len(s)):
        v1[0] = i + 1
        for j in range(len(t)):
            cost = 0 if s[i] == t[j] else 1
            v1[j + 1] = min(v1[j] + 1, v0[j + 1] + 1, v0[j] + cost)
        for j in range(len(v0)):
            v0[j] = v1[j]

    return v1[len(t)]

and I use the pandas.DataFrame.apply to compute the minimum distance between each sequence of the DataFrame with these of the l, which is really slow. Can I use the polars library to speed things up?

To solve this efficiently, you'll likely need to write a polars plugin in rust. Its not as hard as it sounds. Take a look here for some inspiration.

https://github.com/ion-elgreco/polars-distance

I saw that @DeanMacGregor's link has Levenshtein distance, but on strings. I am afraid that I was looking for a more plug n play solution due to time limitations that I have these days. When I will try it, I will update the post. Thank you both for your answers.

@DeanMacGregor I tried the dist_str.levenshtein() of your link's repo but as I expected it probably works just for strings. As I said in OP, I want to compute Levenshtein distance between sequences of tuples. Is that possible from that repo?
